# Problem using any docks (Cairo, AWN, Docky)

Tags: 11.04, dock, cairo

I installed Cairo dock in 11.04, but I cannot add any shortcuts to the Cairo bar. Before that I installed AWN and Docky and I had the same problem. Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

How did you try adding application shortcuts to the Docky bar? In Docky open up an application that you don't have docked, opposite click on it's icon that shows up on the docky bar (Because even if you don't have it docked it'll still show on the dock) and choose `Pin To Dock`